# Finding Specific Child Element Using SQL OPENXML

Tags: sql, xml, openxml

Given this XML:

```
<ArrayOfCandidate>
    <Candidate>
        <Candidate_Serial>a4wwj48pypxg</Candidate_Serial>
        <Job_Serial>a2wwj48c92qp</Job_Serial>
        <Job_Name>Janitor</Job_Name>
        <First_Name>Phillip</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Fry</Last_Name>
        <Email>phillip_fry@yahoo.com</Email>
        <Address_1>123 Main St</Address_1>
        <Questionnaires>
            <Questionnaire>
                <Questionnaire_Name>Questionnaire 1</Questionnaire_Name>
                <Questionnaire_Serial>a7wwj48rbcwx</Questionnaire_Serial>
                <Submit_Date>04/29/2020 10:55 AM</Submit_Date>
                <Submit_Date_Timestamp>1588175742</Submit_Date_Timestamp>
                <Questions>
                    <QuestionObject>
                        <Question>Salary Requirements</Question>
                        <Value>36.00 per hour</Value>
                    </QuestionObject>
                    <QuestionObject>
                        <Question>Are you eligible to work in the US?</Question>
                        <Value>Yes</Value>
                    </QuestionObject>
                </Questions>
            </Questionnaire>
            <Questionnaire>
                <Questionnaire_Name>New Employee Information Sheet</Questionnaire_Name>
                <Questionnaire_Serial>a7wwj488ril8</Questionnaire_Serial>
                <Submit_Date>05/18/2020 11:52 AM</Submit_Date>
                <Submit_Date_Timestamp>1589820723</Submit_Date_Timestamp>
                <Questions>
                    <QuestionObject>
                        <Question>Zip Code</Question>
                        <Value>86327</Value>
                    </QuestionObject>
                    <QuestionObject>
                        <Question>Phone Number</Question>
                        <Value>252-915-1623</Value>
                    </QuestionObject>
                    <QuestionObject>
                        <Question>Social Security Number</Question>
                        <Value>414-62-7741</Value>
                    </QuestionObject>
                </Questions>
            </Questionnaire>
        </Questionnaires>
    </Candidate>
</ArrayOfCandidate>
```

I have been able to use the index of `<Questionnaire>` and `<QuestionObject>` to find the value, but I cannot guarantee the indices to always be the same.

```
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XMLData  
            
select *
from    openxml(@idoc,'/ArrayOfCandidate/Candidate', 1)
with (
      Candidate_Serial      nvarchar(max)   'Candidate_Serial'
    , First_Name            nvarchar(max)   'First_Name'
    , Last_Name             nvarchar(max)   'Last_Name'
    , Email                 nvarchar(max)   'Email'
    , Address_1             nvarchar(max)   'Address_1'
    , SSN                   nvarchar(max)   'Questionnaires/Questionnaire[2]/Questions/QuestionObject[3]/Value'
) c;
```

Is it possible to rewrite the query matching on the `<Questionnaire_Name>` element with the text of `New Employee Information Sheet` and the `<Question>` element with the text of `Social Security Number`

Comment: It is better to use XQuery methods .nodes() and .value() instead of the proprietary OPENXML.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I try to avoid XQuery as it much slower for queries where there are a large number of elements to process, which is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It will find SSN regardless of its sequential position.

Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is better to use XQuery language, based on the w3c standards, while dealing with the XML data type.

Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
It is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<ArrayOfCandidate>
    <Candidate>
        <Candidate_Serial>a4wwj48pypxg</Candidate_Serial>
        <Job_Serial>a2wwj48c92qp</Job_Serial>
        <Job_Name>Janitor</Job_Name>
        <First_Name>Phillip</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Fry</Last_Name>
        <Email>phillip_fry@yahoo.com</Email>
        <Address_1>123 Main St</Address_1>
        <Questionnaires>
            <Questionnaire>
                <Questionnaire_Name>Questionnaire 1</Questionnaire_Name>
                <Questionnaire_Serial>a7wwj48rbcwx</Questionnaire_Serial>
                <Submit_Date>04/29/2020 10:55 AM</Submit_Date>
                <Submit_Date_Timestamp>1588175742</Submit_Date_Timestamp>
                <Questions>
                    <QuestionObject>
                        <Question>Salary Requirements</Question>
                        <Value>36.00 per hour</Value>
                    </QuestionObject>
                    <QuestionObject>
                        <Question>Are you eligible to work in the US?</Question>
                        <Value>Yes</Value>
                    </QuestionObject>
                </Questions>
            </Questionnaire>
            <Questionnaire>
                <Questionnaire_Name>New Employee Information Sheet</Questionnaire_Name>
                <Questionnaire_Serial>a7wwj488ril8</Questionnaire_Serial>
                <Submit_Date>05/18/2020 11:52 AM</Submit_Date>
                <Submit_Date_Timestamp>1589820723</Submit_Date_Timestamp>
                <Questions>
                    <QuestionObject>
                        <Question>Zip Code</Question>
                        <Value>86327</Value>
                    </QuestionObject>
                    <QuestionObject>
                        <Question>Phone Number</Question>
                        <Value>252-915-1623</Value>
                    </QuestionObject>
                    <QuestionObject>
                        <Question>Social Security Number</Question>
                        <Value>414-62-7741</Value>
                    </QuestionObject>
                </Questions>
            </Questionnaire>
        </Questionnaires>
    </Candidate>
</ArrayOfCandidate>';

SELECT c.value('(Candidate_Serial/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Candidate_Serial
    , c.value('(First_Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as First_Name
    , c.value('(Last_Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Last_Name
    , c.value('(Email/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Email
    , c.value('(Address_1/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)') as Address_1
    , c.value('(Questionnaires/Questionnaire/Questions/QuestionObject[Question/text()="Social Security Number"]/Value/text())[1]', 'CHAR(11)') as SSN
FROM @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfCandidate/Candidate') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+------------------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------+
| Candidate_Serial | First_Name | Last_Name |         Email         |  Address_1  |     SSN     |
+------------------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------+
| a4wwj48pypxg     | Phillip    | Fry       | phillip_fry@yahoo.com | 123 Main St | 414-62-7741 |
+------------------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------+
```